# How to given Project Path if Jenkins Integration with Git Hub

Tags: jenkins, github

The below is the command line  execution for the automated build to schedule from Jenkins.. This is working fine.

```
cd C:\Users\3020722\Downloads\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.3.0
katalon.exe  -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\Users\3020722\Katalon_Studio\PoC\PoC.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/POCTestSuite" -browserType="IE"
```

I need to take the latest project from the gitHub... How the workflow for the command line execution.

```
1. Clone Project in to local directory 
2. Use that directory in the command line execution
```

Is it the case first it needs to clone into always local path (pre-defined) and that path needs to be given. Can you please let me know how the workflow for gitHub to Jenkins

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize WORKSPACE variable from Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Just put it directly into Katalon Studio command and Jenkins will parse it automatically, e.g:

```
katalon.exe  -runMode=console -projectPath="%WORKSPACE%\PoC.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/POCTestSuite" -browserType="IE"
```

Comment: I wanted to pull the project from Git... It will not be generally stored in the jenkins root directory.. it would be some other folder.. I want to know the procedure how to get the projects?